# How to avoid interruption of .animate method in Fabric.JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

On this script below , red square will move to the clicked point .

```
    let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {width: 500,height: 500});
    let square = new fabric.Rect({left: 100,top: 100,width: 50,height: 50,fill: 'red' });

    canvas.add(square);

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {
        let x = options.e.x;
        let y = options.e.y;
        square.animate ({ left: x, top: y }, { 
            onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
            duration: 500
        });
    })
```

But if you click on another point  while square is moving , it wil change it's destination on a new point
Why is this happening ?

From my point of view the script flow is this:

1) on mouse down event , .animate callback goes to event que

2) when it fires red square starts changing it's coordinates with calling canvas.requestRenderAll()

3)If you click to other point , another callback (callback2) goes to event que.

It fires relatively fast , so red square changes its destination starting from the point where it was when callback 2 fires

Is this correct ?

How can i avoid such behaivior ? What I need is that red squre move to the first point and no new click would change it's way . Only when square complete it's movement we can choose new point , where it will move

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler, you can immediately make it remove itself before starting the animation, and reattach itself in the `onComplete` callback:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

let square = new fabric.Rect({left: 100,top: 100,width: 50,height: 50,fill: 'red' });

canvas.add(square);
const handler = function (options) {
  //remove handler
  this.off('mouse:down', handler);
  let x = options.e.x;
  let y = options.e.y;
  square.animate ({ left: x, top: y }, { 
    onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
    onComplete: () => {
      //reattach handler
      this.on('mouse:down', handler);
    },
    duration: 2000
  });
}
canvas.on('mouse:down', handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

(I slowed the animation down a bit for testing purposes)